# Android sdk manager not found

Tags: flutter

How can I fix this error ?

```
$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
Android sdkmanager tool not found (E:\Android Studio\android-sdk-windows-1.6_r1\tools\bin\sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring android studio path using the command `flutter config --android-studio-dir <Your Path To Android Studio>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved the problem on a brand new install of Android Studio :

1. In Android Studio, open SDK Manager
2. Go to the **SDK Tools** tab
3. Uncheck **Hide obsolete packages**. That will display more tools in the list.
4. Check **Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)** in the list
5. Click Apply or OK